# Invalid primary key datatype [int]

Tags: sql-server-2000, castle-activerecord, generator

I am using Afo Castle AR Code Generator v1.0.0.4 at first I was receiving errors for using tinyint as a primary key so I changed those to int but the only error I have left and can't seem to get rid of is

> Invalid primary key datatype [int] for
>   table dbo.Level_Code.  Only int
>   identity and uniqueidentifier primary
>   keys are supported in the free
>   version.

The field is already an int in the database. I even tried changing it from an int to tinyint and then back but that still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says it only supports an autogenerating int key. Make the int an identity as well and you should be fine.